# Can the Kindle app scroll mobi files vertically?

Tags: ebooks, kindle-for-android

The Kindle Android app makes the mobi files scroll horizontally. This poses a problem if a certain portion of the text is in the previous *page* and I need to keep scrolling left and right. Instead can it let me scroll *selectively* from top to bottom? How?